# QGIS Show several images for a feature (Image Slider widget)

Tags: qgis

I have a layer where each feature can have more than one image. Some have 1 photo, some 5 photos, some 15.

I would like to be able to show all available photos of a item in QGIS. The available Photo Widget is only capable os showing one photo.

My photos have the following nomenclature:

```
00001_01.jpg: first image of feature id 1
00001_02.jpg: second image of feature id 1
00001_03.jpg: third image of feature id 1
00002_01.jpg: first image of feature id 2
00003_01.jpg: first image of feature id 3
00003_02.jpg: second image of feature id 3
.....
```

I know that there is not a slider widget in QGIS but is there a way to view all the photos for each feature?

Comment: I'm looking for the same feature here. I found eVis plugin to view pics but it is linked on one field only. It is still easier than internal qgis actions.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 3.x there is an image slider plugin called "**MapSwipe Tool**".

Homepage: https://github.com/lmotta/mapswipetool_plugin

Demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLIugXYG5qs

It works in 3.28. You may swipe horizontally or vertically.
[image]

[image]